# is iPhone/iPad required for Apple Developer Program?

Tags: iphone, ipad, developer-program

do I need an iPhone/iPad to make a developer account ?

as I getting this message

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to enroll from? You need a Mac to build apps, no matter how you sign up.

Comment: I am trying to enroll from the web.
I am building with flutter in windows. when it is time to deploy I will borrow a Mac.

Comment: Sorry - I can't test the signup process, as I'm already signed up. Did you start from your AppleID with 2FA?